# 1020 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-1020

As we know 1020 gets up-to 38mp in default camera app. But what about 1020 with windows 10 ? Does the default windows camera app on 10 support 38mp? Or does any other 3rd party app supports that kind of quality!
I badly need to know this because am planning to go for it only because of its 41mp camera. If windows 10 doesn't support it, then it will be a waste to buy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lumia 1020 is not in the supported list of phone that are eligible for Windows 10 upgrade. You can see the list of eligible phones [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-mobile-upgrade?4161f8f5-7e1c-4e98-a5ed-28262407d074=1). So it is best to stay in Windows phone 8.1.

Regarding your question the Lumia Camera app worked better on Lumia 1020 during the Insider preview in Windows 10. Windows 10 default camera app had some problems with Lumia 1020's camera.

Answer (score 1):

So far it doesn't look like the L1020 will get W10. At least mine hasn't received an update, yet. So I wouldn't base your decision on that. So far I wouldn't even upgrade if W10 was available, as Microsoft has proven, that some features do get a lot worse on a new Version. (e.g. Onedrive in W10 is a joke compared to W8.1)
Especially Nokia Drive will not be supported on W10, so if you want to enjoy the camera, do it with W8. And try out the camera before buying it, as it's a lot slower than newer Lumia models, who use PureView on fewer pixels.

Answer (score 1):

### It still Rocks! Lumia 1020- for what it is made for.

In my experience atleast, Nokia Camera app (aka Lumia Camera) works equally great for me in Windows 10 Mobile as it used to in Widows Phone 8.x. I always use RAW output for my final work mostly. *(It only struggles w/ RED highlights)*

I've learnt photography through this camera in my early amateur days. And I still love doing with it. Only thing you need w/ it is patience though!

---

**Additional Information:**

I've recently recovered my (bricked) Lumia 1020. And upgraded it to Windows 10 Mobile 15254.527 (w/ Aug 2018 update). I've been using this phone since 2014 and also active as an Insider. From my experience now, all I can say is:

> **Its working so much better** than Preview builds of W10. I'm **currently on Windows 10 Mobile 1709**. It is quite stable and all of those much needed apps are working good.

(Fluent design elements are working in apps like Groove Music, Store, etc.)

Currently working apps in my device:

- Lumia Camera (aka Nokia Pro Cam / Nokia Camera),
- All the "Angry Birds" ;)
- Camera 360 Sight
- CamScanner
- Flipkart
- Groove Music (it is quite good actually)
- Hyperlapse Mobile
- Instagram
- Lumia Panorama (& other Lumia apps)
- News
- Opera Mini(but it sucks),
- Paytm,
- Saavn,
- SHARE.it,
- SBI app,
- Telegram,
- Whatsapp,
- VLC

And I would like to say that FB, Messenger & few other apps were also working and they've got improved UI, but I'm not using them currently.

> I am using it for photography and telephony (of-course), a few games, loads of songs, sometimes chat and internet.
>
> ### Working Tweaks
>
> (thanks to XDA, etcetra) I've got fully functional **LED Notification**. (Windows button in Nav bar), **Glance Screen** with background image, **Brightness slider** (instead of Low/Med/High its Darkest settings really helps in the night), **Lockscreen timeout to: Never** (helps in preventing Lumia's hotspot disconnection) and a few other minor tweaks working.

*Also, I found the following bummer(s) in the latest W10M:*

- Truecaller and UC Browser are not longer available.
- Amazon app, Olacabs are crashing
- 'Here' ecosystem (Here Maps, Here Drive, etc.) only works upto build 10586.xxx & Windows Maps are not working properly.

  I used Maps a lot back in WP8.1, but in W10M they are kinda non-sense. Only Satellite view is usable. Aerial view is unable to render streets from up-close. (I'm currently working on this problem. Because I found out that GPU in my Lumia is not being used when I use Maps...Help needed!)
- Instagram sometimes crashes and lags, but it works decently and that's okay for me, atleast.
  *Remember: WP8.1 only provides Instagram beta :(*
- Project my screen app is not working for me, I guess because I've USB 3.0 ports on my PC and it is said to have problems with that.
- I've only encountered 3 unexpected restarts in around 20 days.

---

PS: I still need to check the performance & heating of device for Hyperlapse Mobile and Long video's for time-lapses.

---

[image: LED Notification]
[image: About]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it supports that. Windows 10 is the successor of Windows 8(.1), so it'll same or better according to Microsoft. It would be weird if the next version of  an operating system would become worse than before. You don't have to worry about the mp. Microsoft is working hard to Keep improving it. I hope that will help you.